# How to use Screen Mirroring. What network protocol does Screen Mirroring use?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 4.3-jelly-bean, screen, ad-hoc-networks

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII (GT-I9300) which supports Screen Mirroring. I would like
to use this feature to share my screen with a Samsung Galaxy S Plus (GT-I9001) running
Android Gingerbread or with a Windows 7 or Vista computer or Sony Bravia TV. However,
when I try to activate the feature on the SIII by clicking `Settings -> Connections -> Screen Mirroring` I get a message that says "Available Devices   Scanning...   No devices found".

Does Screen Mirroring need to be available (and enabled) on both devices, or on just one
device? Do I need to have any special software for it to work?
How do I get this feature to work?

Thanks.

Comment: I have found a description of screen mirroring to PC devices on the [following page](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000058/14070/167504/N/1/M/UN55F7450AFXZA). Apparently, since I am running Android 4.3, I need to install [this patch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.screenmirroringpatch&hl=en) to get Screen Mirroring to work on my Android device. When I press the Source button on my TV's remote control I see I can select various input sources including `Digital, Analog, AV1, AV2, HDMI1, HDMI2, Component, PC`, no `Screen Mirroring` input source, so no luck.

Comment: I've downloaded the patch but when I tried to launch the `ScreenMirroring Patch` application I got a message stating that the patch was not needed, so I guess my device applied the patch automatically.

Comment: The [following page](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/best-screen-mirroring-devices,review-2286.html) contains some more information.

Comment: A physical HDMI adapter device for TVs powered via a microUSB port called the Chromecast can be plugged into a TV to make it support the Screen Mirroring feature for streaming your Android devices' screen to the TV. However, this solution apparently also requires the Chromecast app to be installed on the Android device and this requires Android 4.4.2 or higher, hence this solution is not compatible with my device.

Comment: Another solution is to plug a [Miracast](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wireless-display-adapter#details) USB-powered HDMI adapter into the TV or computer monitor to which the data is to be streamed, and stream from an Android 4.2.1 device (streaming from Windows 8.1 PCs and phones is also supported), but this solution again also requires you to purchase the physical adapter so this solution doesn't work out-of-the-box. Regards.